# Trying to upgrade to 14.04 from 13.10, and I keep getting the same error message

Tags: upgrade, updates, software-center, update-manager

I've had no problems upgrading from one version of Ubuntu to the next until lately.  Now, every time I attempt to upgrade, I get the following error message:

```
W:Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty-backports/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80], 
W:Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty-backports/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80], 
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

There was a bit more but I can't post more than 2 links currently.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `natty-backports` line (and any other `natty` line) from your `sources.list`. ("Natty" refers to Ubuntu 11.04, which is no longer supported and has been removed from the archive mirrors, hence the 404.)

Comment: Well that might just have done it!  I'm a lot further along in the process than I was.  I'll update when it finishes.  Thank you!